# Rails 3 using Devise: How to allow someone to log in using their Facebook account?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise

I have a Rails 3 application using [Devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication. Now I need to allow someone to log in using their Facebook account. I think this is called Facebook Connect, but I've also heard the term Facebook Graph API, so I'm not sure which one I'm asking for.

What do I need to do in order to integrate Facebook Connect with Devise?

### Solution:

This question is pretty old now. A year ago, Devise v1.2 introduced [OmniAuth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) support. Now Devise is at v2.1 (as of this writing) and using OmniAuth is even easier. Here is a great tutorial from the Devise wiki on [using the `omniauth-facebook` gem with Devise to allow sign-in using Facebook](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview).

Also check out this great tutorial on [registering your application and working with the Facebook Graph API](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook).

Comment: Devise v1.3 came out. Use that instead of instead of head or branch version

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Devise 1.2 now comes with facebook login support using omniauth and works with Rails 3.0. Check out the [wiki entry](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview).

Comment: No more trunk/head version. New version of devise came out. Use 1.3 https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/v1.3.0

Comment: Works great, thanks! How can I work with the Graph/OpenGraph API once authenticated? Use another gem such as Koala?

Answer (score 54):

I checked the devise github page to see what they were up to. That project is moving pretty fast and as it happens they have support for facebook connect amongst other things. Check out the section on OAuth2. They use github as an example but it would be the same thing for facebook and they mention differences. I think this is the way to go, third party gems for devise don't move as fast as devise or rails do. Cheers.

Oops here's the link http://github.com/plataformatec/devise

**Edit**

Of course I did very little coding here mostly went with the default, so here goes:

Create a new app and add these gems to the gemfile.

```
gem 'devise', :git => 'git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git'
gem 'oauth2', :git => 'git://github.com/intridea/oauth2.git'
```

Run bundle install, then these commands gets you going with a basic User authentication model.

```
rails generate devise:install
rails generate devise User
```

In config/initializers/devise.rb uncomment/modify these. Look at the last paragraph as to where you get app_key and secret from facebook.

```
config.oauth :facebook, 'app_key', 'secret',
    :site              => 'https://graph.facebook.com',
    :authorize_path    => '/oauth/authorize',
    :access_token_path => '/oauth/access_token'
```

This should be your user model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :oauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :oauthable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
    # Get the user email info from Facebook for sign up
    # You'll have to figure this part out from the json you get back
    data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(access_token)

    if user = User.find_by_email(data["email"])
      user
    else
      # Create an user with a stub password.
      User.create!(:name => data["name"], :email => data["email"], :password => Devise.friendly_token)
    end
  end
end
```

Devise uses a root :to => "something#here" so I created a home controller with a index action and used that to root the application. But nevermind that. I put that in layout/application.html.erb so that I had basic sign_n sign_out routes.

```
<span>
  <%- if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= "Signed in as #{current_user.full_name}. Not you?" %>
    <%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path %>
  <%- else %>
    <%= link_to 'Sign in', new_user_session_path %>
  <%- end %>
</span>
```

Devise pretty much takes care of everything else for us. What you do need to do though is get your app_key and secret from facebook (used in devise.rb config file). This link should get you going. http://developers.facebook.com/setup

Comment: I think you are right. Facebook's new authentication API uses OAuth2. I have never worked with OAuth, nor Facebook, nor Devise. So I could use some extra help. Could you elaborate on what I would need to do in order to get it working with Facebook?

Comment: Sure I'll take a crack at it, I'll work something out later this evening and post you some code to get you going.

Comment: This answer got the highest score but [it's actually out-of-dated](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1104).  It doesn't work anymore on recent version of devise.  Use omniauth instead.

Comment: Yes that is why it's no longer, the accepted answer aswel. Honest question: should I update it to simply say to use devise omniauth?

Comment: Intridea published an article on the day it released omniauth 1.0  http://intridea.com/2011/11/2/omniauth-1-0.  The author explains the philosophies behind 1.0 and why they break API compatibility.  Since omniauth has tons of 3rd-party strategies support and the legacy email/password authentication is also implemented in omniauth-identity, omniauth 1.0 becomes a total solution for web auth.  My suggestion would be that just abandon devise and use omniauth 1.0 with various strategy gems you need.

Comment: hey! user still don't know the stub password created for him! please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739104/what-is-recommended-for-handling-password-for-new-facebook-signed-in-users

Comment: @Hugo I have created a whole app here https://github.com/mohitjain/social-login-in-rails. Let me know if you want to update your answer with this repo. It has integrations will all the popular social networks like facebook, linkedin, google, github, twitter.

Answer (score 8):

In my app, I use omniauth, which I think came out a bit after this question was answered.

https://github.com/intridea/omniauth

Comment: OmniAuth is awesome, and it works well with Devise, as seen in this Railscasts episode (and the following one): http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1

Comment: yeah, I'll definitely be using omniauth next time.

Answer (score 6):

This [blog post](http://stjhimy.com/posts/14-allowing-devise-login-with-facebook-account) did it for me. Give it a look.

Comment: That's a great post. Thanks for that.

Comment: Instructions on that post are based on a non-released version of devise. [reference](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1104)

Answer (score 6):

Just used Hugo solution with almost no problem. Here is the User.rb code I had to use :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :oauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :oauthable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
    # Get the user email info from Facebook for sign up
    # You'll have to figure this part out from the json you get back

    data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(access_token.get('https://graph.facebook.com/me?'))

    logger.info("received from Facebook: #{data.inspect}")

    if user = User.find_by_email(data["email"])
      user
    else
      # Create an user with a stub password.
      User.create!(:name => data["name"], :email => data["email"], :password => Devise.friendly_token)
    end
  end
end
```

The things changed in this code :

- name is in attr_accessible (don't forget to add a name field to user)
- changed JSON decoding

Answer (score 3):

http://github.com/grimen/devise_facebook_connectable

This gem on github is quite straightforward. Worth a shot!

Comment: does not work with Rails 3: http://www.railsplugins.org/plugins/179-devise-facebook-connect

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small application with integrates with Devise + Twitter + Facebook + Linkedin + Google + Github. All in one place.

You can find source [here](https://github.com/mohitjain/social-login-in-rails) and a demo [here](http://social-login-in-rails.herokuapp.com/)