# Can I use rails' devise to integrate linkedin connect to my site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, linkedin-api

I have a Rails 3 application using Devise for authentication. 
In addition to the manual authentication using email, I also have a facebook connect that allows a single sign-in using facebook. 
The next step is linkedin connect. Is there a simple way to integrate linkedin API call to devise?

(The naive approach of defining 

`config.oauth :linkedin, 'MY_APP_ID','MY_APP_SECRET',

      :site              => 'https://api.linkedin.com/',

      :authorize_path    => '/uas/oauth/authorize',

      :access_token_path => '/uas/oauth/accessToken'`

in the config/initializers/devise.rb resulted in "An Authorization Token was not supplied" error message from linkedin).

Thanks!

Update:
Thanks for the (incredibly) fast replies. I was hoping not to have to change my application to add the linkedin authentication, by using omniauth or a similiar solution. However, I now see that the linkedin response doesn't return the email - which is the used as the primary key for my users, and hence I cannot use the authentication the way I use facebook (In Ryan's solution he allows to define the email separately if not returned from twitter, but it's not good enough for my purposes).

Another Update:
Devise now has omniauth support, and it is working nicely.
Checkout [this link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2

http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [OmniAuth](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1) railscast for an awesome tutorial on how to integrate Facebook Connect with devise. Good luck!

Comment: Devise on its own doesn't do FBConnect - you must be using a plugin.  You'll need a similar plugin/gem for linkedin, or you can use something like Omniauth (see Sam's link) or Janrain's Engage service to integrate many such services easily.

Comment: It actually does. Check out the example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580557/rails-3-using-devise-how-to-allow-someone-to-log-in-using-their-facebook-account