# what is recommended for handling password for new Facebook signed in users?

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise, facebook-authentication

When let users sign in using Facebook, I create a new devise user after first authentication, the question is what is the better practice to do regarding the password of newly created user ?

**1. Fill it with a random token?**

Then, how would the user know the newly created password ?

> a. Shall I send him an email?
>   b. Write it as a flash message after his first Facebook authentication
>   ?

*I know that user might not need to have a password as he can always sign in with Facebook, but, he might need to update his devise user fields, which will require the password.*

**2. Leave it blank?**

> Then, any one know the email will be able to sign in using the devise
>   sign in form.

**3. Show a modal window asking for password?**

> Doing so, it will add a step before user can eventually access the
>   website.

So, what's the recommended approach? any advise?

**EDIT**

Ryan Bates on RailsCasts at 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2?view=asciicast

redirect the user to a form where they can fix any problems if the validation fails when trying to save the new user, he avoided rendering passwords fields for brand-new users:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <p><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :email %></p>

<% if @user.password_required? %>
  <p><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></p>
<% end %>
  <p><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></p>
<% end %>

<%= render :partial => "devise/shared/links" %>
```

But, what will happen when a OmniAuth registered user try sign in using devise sign in ?

Comment: I think you're using both Omniauth and Devise registration on your web site, right ? I've been in the same case, I checked the provider attribute of User to allow only registered users to login with their email. Facebook have to login with their Facebook account.

Comment: Hi again Samir, nice to see you moving on now :)

Comment: @Baldrick, that's an idea .. easy to implement too, so you tell people (flash message ?) to sign in with their Facebook in case they have to ?

Comment: If a User with the provider 'facebook' tries to login with its email using the Devise form, I show an error message indicating that he must login with its facebook account (or what whatever is its provider).

Comment: This is a safe way, and for any reason, you still can contact your users

Comment: I use your first alternative, i.e., auto-generate a password for the user. Include instructions in the welcome email about how to reset the password (i.e., forgot password). It takes the least code, and I think is the most correct way to handle it.

Comment: Yes, I think this a convenient way, thanks

Comment: Can you please add your comments as an answer, so that I mark it as a correct answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ryan Bates covered this on RailsCasts and suggests you redirect them to a page after they've signed up with their oauth account.

This way you can still register users in the normal way plus you're sill validating the model.

We do this so out customers can sign up with different providers and still keep our devise registration in place.

Have a read of this:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2?view=asciicast

If that's not helpful, let me know and I'll see what else we can find for you

Comment: It seems that Ryan doesn't render email fields when redirecting to new_user_registration_url for brand users, which means that password will be nil ? so point number 2 is applied ?! please see EDIT above

Comment: Hey. We have our devise registration paths in place and also allow customers to signup with facebook and add only their email. I think the code for that was in my previous answer. It gets confusing I know!!

Comment: I think implementing point 3 is a nice way, adding a 'Not Now' button, so that user can enter his devise account's password later, what do you think ?

Comment: What are you going to do with non FB users? Or are you disabling that?

Comment: They still can easily register with a devise form at my site