# what is the best/fastest way to develop a login system in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, rubygems

what is the best way to develop a login system along with registering panel for register using twitter or fb and own database . Is there any gems for that. As I am very new to ruby , pls help me with this :)

I know about scaffolds . but want more functionalities .

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: DEVISE gem will manage your users, authentication, etc. ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580557/rails-3-using-devise-how-to-allow-someone-to-log-in-using-their-facebook-accoun ) See the Devise doc: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Answer (score 2):

On rails, [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), because it addresses controllers and views too. Also have a lot of plugins. You might want to check the [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise).

Comment: @Mindbreaker strangelly I'm always switching the () for [] while writing the links today. Thanks.

Comment: @SagiruddinMondal there are screencasts that you need to pay, but this one is free. Click in the link, then click in `Click to play video` - just try and it is working here

Comment: this link is not clickable !!

Comment: @fotanus i tested the link. But you can also download the episode, if the player not work for you.

Comment: here it is written "Click to play video" but it is not clickable ... can u pls give me the link of screencast directly ?

Comment: @SagiruddinMondal It opens in the same page, maybe you are missing a plugin in your browser? Any way, here is the [direct download link](http://media.railscasts.com/assets/episodes/sources/209-introducing-devise.zip) that Mindbreaker mentionated